# Is there a way to programmatically access the “Share WiFI password” feature on iOS or Android?

Tags: networking, mobile, iot, smartphone

I feel sure this question has already been asked and answered, but I can’t find a link, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

I want to be able to pass the wifi SSID and Password to an IoT device programmatically, but don't want to use WPS.  I want to achieve something similar to the Share WiFi password feature on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

no .. for security reasons there is no way to access the wifi password on a ios device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Sorry to persist, but, is there no native API that fires a pop-up i.e. “share WiFi password” on iOS, which allows the user to opt to share?  Though as I write this I guess the security concerns still exist.

Answer (score 0):

In android there are several third party unofficial tools which claim to be able to retrieve it, as soon as the device is rooted, and hence it creates also legal and guaranty issues